# I want to save python variable result to a file

Tags: python, file

when this files run gives corresponding output values as;

```
# test BLE Scanning software
# jcs 6/8/2014


import MySQLdb as my
import blescan
import sys


import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez

dev_id = 0

db = my.connect(host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="root",
db="test"
)

cursor = db.cursor()

try:
    sock = bluez.hci_open_dev(dev_id)
    print "ble thread started"

except:
    print "error accessing bluetooth device..."
        sys.exit(1)

blescan.hci_le_set_scan_parameters(sock)
blescan.hci_enable_le_scan(sock)




while True:
    returnedList = blescan.parse_events(sock, 10)
    print "----------"
    for beacon in returnedList:

        print beacon


sql = "insert into beacon VALUES(null, '%s')" % \
(beacon)

number_of_rows = cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()

db.close()
```

I want output stored in  a text file

```
cf:68:cc:c7:33:10,b9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d,13072,52423,-74,-78
cf:68:cc:c7:33:10,74696d6f74650e160a181033c7cc68cf,46608,13255,-52,-77
da:f4:2e:a0:70:b1,b9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d,28849,11936,-74,-79
da:f4:2e:a0:70:b1,74696d6f74650e160a18b170a02ef4da,46769,28832,46,-78
dd:5d:d3:35:09:dd,8aefb0316c32486f825be26fa193487d,1,1,-64,-78
c3:11:48:9b:cf:fa,8aefb0316c32486f825be26fa193487d,0,0,-64,-73
fd:5b:12:7f:02:e4,b9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d,740,4735,-74,-79
fd:5b:12:7f:02:e4,74696d6f74650e160a18e4027f125bfd,46820,639,18,-80
dd:5d:d3:35:09:dd,8aefb0316c32486f825be26fa193487d,1,1,-64,-77
```

so on... and then write store these values in text file. For text file, is it possible to generate text file as a part of script? Thanks

Comment: [Yes!](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) Is your beacon a simple list?

Comment: yes and i want to save the 
iBeacon MAC Address

iBeacon UDID

iBeacon Major Number

iBeacon Minor Number

TX Power at 1m

results to a mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your loop

```
while True:
    returnedList = blescan.parse_events(sock, 10)
    print "----------"
    f = open('bluez.txt', 'a+')
    for beacon in returnedList:
        print beacon
        f.write(','.join(beacon)+'\n')
    f.close()
```

EDIT: now appending mode

Comment: Are you sure you want to overwrite the file every time through the while loop?

Comment: not overwrite though,i want to append the results

Comment: is it possible to  save those values  in a mysql database table?

Comment: if you want to save to mysql, you may want to look at the sqlalchemy module

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is to store the data in file, so you can open it later the simplest way is to use the [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) (or the [cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle)) module
something like:

```
import cPickle

#store the data in file

with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(returnedList, f)

#to read the data

loaded_returnedList = cPickle.load(open('/path/to/file.txt'))

 print loaded_returnedList == returnedList # Prints True
```

now if what you want is store the data for visual store (maybe to open it in excel later), the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module is for you

```
import csv

with open('/path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for beacon in returnedList:
        writer.writerow(beacon)
```

Comment: it gives me a writer = csv.writer(f) expected an indented block

Comment: you are probably coping it without the 4 spaces at the beginning. remember in python indentation its really important.